# WHOIS in Mac OS terminal not doing anything

Tags: macos, whois

I'm not getting any output at all when doing a simple WHOIS command in the macOS terminal.

Just seems to run and then is ready for the next command. Every online tutorial or article I've seen shows a response back with the WHOIS information.

Why isn't this working for me?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me either and I have no idea why.  However, `whois -i apple.com` gives reasonable results if you're looking for a workaround rather than an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whois` doesn't know where to look up that domain.

You'll need to provide:

1. An `-h <host>` to a register, eg `whois.markmonitor.com`
2. Use `-i` option to use *the traditional Network Information Center* <sup>[[link]](https://www.internic.net/)</sup>

---

From `man whois`:

> `-h host`
>
> Use the specified host instead of the default.  Either a host name or an IP address may be specified.
>
> ---
>
> `-i`
>
> Use the traditional Network Information Center (InterNIC) (whois.internic.net) database.  **This now contains only registrations for domain names under .COM, .NET, .EDU.**  You can specify the type of
> object to search for like whois -i 'type name' where type can be domain, nameserver, registrar.  The name can contain * wildcards.

<sup>[[`man` link]](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whois)</sup>

---

For example, instead of `whois google.com`, use

1. ```
   whois -h whois.markmonitor.com google.com
   ```
2. ```
   whois -i google.com
   ```

---

Both the `-h` and `-i` will output slightly different results.

A glims of a CLI output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Just using whois -i apple.com is working fine for me.

Comment: The `-i` is fine in most cases. Just remember it only contains **com**, **net** and **edu** as shown in the man page quote above.